# Use a CAS and the concept of level curves to plot representative graphs of members of the family of solutions of the differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use a CAS and the concept of level curves to plot representative graphs of members
of the family of solutions of the differential equation
$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{8x + 5}{3y^2 + 1}$.
.
Which after integrating gives:
$y^3+y = 4x^2+5x +c$

$y^3+y - 4x^2-5x =c$

$\hspace{400pt}$
$\:$Experiment with different numbers of level curves as well as various rectangular regions
defined by a$\leqslant$ x $\leqslant$ b and c $\leqslant$ y $\leqslant$ d.
(b) On separate coordinate axes plot the graphs of the particular solutions corresponding
to the initial conditions: y(0) = −1; y(0) = 2; y(−1) = 4; y(−1) = −3.

I have tried plotting the level curves with wolfram Mathematica as given below.
[image] Ineed some help in verifying my answer.

Comment: Did the two solutions answer your questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you need the curves for various $c$, then for part a., we have:

```
ContourPlot[y^3 + y - 4 x^2 - 5 x, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  Contours -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image]

We can also obtain the same thing using a phase plane (direction field) with a bunch of initial conditions.

[image]

For part b., we use the initial condition to solve for $c$ and get $c = (-2,10,69,-29)$.

If we plot the four solution sets for these, we get:

```
ContourPlot[y^3 + y - 4 x^2 - 5 x, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  Contours -> {-2, 10, 69, -29}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", ContourStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]
```

[image]

Comment: Also needs a TU! ;-)

Comment: And another one is on the way. $......+1........$

Answer (score 3):

Maple tells the same:

```
 [> sol := dsolve(diff(y(x), x) = (8*x+5)/(3*y(x)^2+1), y(x)):
    tplot := {seq(subs(_C1 = i, rhs(sol[1])), i = -15 .. 15)}:
    plot(tplot, x = -4 .. 4, y = -3 .. 6);
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Nice graphic, Babak! +1

Comment: @BabakS.: It was really nice to see the two solutions by the different CAS tools +1